# How to convert "Thu Jun 11 00:49:35 IST 2015" to "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am getting  date as "Thu Jun 11 00:49:35 IST 2015" from REST API.
When I try to convert it using new Date("Thu Jun 11 00:49:35 IST 2015"), it says "Invalid Date". Is there any other ways to convert it to Date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove "IST" from the source and it will work :

```
var d = new Date("Thu Jun 11 00:49:35 2015");
```

result will be a jscript date with value of :

```
Thu Jun 11 2015 00:49:35 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
```

JavaScript accepts these time zones:

```
Time Zone   Description
UTC Coordinated Universal Time
GMT Greenwich Mean Time
EDT (US) Eastern Daylight Time
CDT (US) Central Daylight Time
MDT (US) Mountain Daylight Time
PDT (US) Pacific Daylight Time
EST (US) Eastern Standard Time
CST (US) Central Standard Time
MST (US) Mountain Standard Time
PST (US) Pacific Standard Time
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse it to milliseconds and then back to date in the format that you want.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_convert

Comment: Thanks @Gavin Thomas

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code

```
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  var s="Thu Jun 11 00:49:35 IST 2015";
  s=s.replace("IST","");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =new Date(s);




  </script>

 </body>
  </html>
```